# How to dynamically create a Excel Workbook and sending as an e-mail Attachment in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to create a work book dynamically in code and without storing it i want to send it as a attachment in e-mail. I am using VSTO in c#. I found few answers for making this happen in openXml. But all the other implementation i have already completed in excel and it will be tough to switch now.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's wrong about storing the file temporarily and deleting it after it has been sent to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `Worksheet.MailEnvelope` property. Under the `MailEnvelope` you should be able to define the recipient, etc. The `MailEnvelope.Item.Send()` method will fire off the email.